# Linking to URLs in layer fields in cmv

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, configurable-map-viewer, hyperlink

I am using the configurable map viewer and I have fields in many of my layers that I want to use to link to documents with URLs.

Does anyone have any idea how I would do this out of the pop-up window?

I figure that I have to configure the identify.js file but I can't figure out how to accomplish what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You can just enable hyperlinks under the display tab for the layer properties. Add a new value field and then paste the exact url link you want for each value. Select the feature with the hyperlink tool and the page should appear.

Answer (score 0):

This is what it should look like:

```
yourID: {
            0: {
                title: 'YourTitle',
                description: '',
                    fieldInfos: [{
                    fieldName: 'value',
                    label: 'yourLabel',
                    visible: true
                }],
                  mediaInfos: [{
                     "title": "",
                     "caption": "",
                     "type": "image",
                     "value": {
                     "sourceURL": "{link}",
                     "linkURL": "{link}"
               }
             }]
         }
        }
```

I found the template here:

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/intro_popuptemplate.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way I do it using some simple HTML.

```
identifies: {
    zoning: {
        9: {
            title: 'Zoning',
            description: [
                '<table class="attrTable">',
                    '<tr valign="top">',
                        '<td class="attrName">Zoning:</td>',
                        '<td class="attrValue">{Zoning8}</td>',
                    '</tr>',
                    '<tr valign="top">',
                        '<td class="attrName">Zoning Ordinance:</td>',
                        '<td class="attrValue"><a href="http://www.cityofpetaluma.net/cdd/plan-zoning.html" target="_blank">Description</td>',
                    '</tr>',
                '</table>'
            ].join('')
        },
```